# how can i show iframe from m3u8, when user hover the player's timeline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, m3u8, hls.js

i was able to open m3u8 format using hls.js, but i have problem, i need to show preview images from m3u8 when user hover the timeline, how to do this, thanks in advance for your answers)

```
 <div
          className="timeline-container"
          onMouseMove={handleTimeLineUpdate}
          onMouseDown={toggleScrubbing}
          ref={timelineContainer}
        >
          <div className="timeline">
            <img className="preview-img" ref={previewImgRef} alt="previewImg" />
            <div className="thumb-indicator"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

there is my functions for getting iframe from m3u8:

```
const getIframePlaylistUrlsFromM3U8 = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(movie.transcode_file);
      const m3u8Content = await response.text();

     
      const iframePlaylistUrls = extractIframePlaylistUrls(m3u8Content);

 
      return iframePlaylistUrls;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching or parsing M3U8 file", error);
      return [];
    }
  };
```

there i have problem, when i log iframePlaylistUrls it has values, but when another function receives it it shows empty

```
  const extractIframePlaylistUrls = (m3u8Content) => {
    const iframePlaylistUrls = parseM3U8(m3u8Content);
    return iframePlaylistUrls;
  };
```

```
  const parseM3U8 = (m3u8Content) => {
    const regex = /EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:.*URI="(.+)"/g;
    const matches = m3u8Content.matchAll(regex);
    return Array.from(matches, (match) => match[1]);
  };
```

```
  const updatePreviewImageOnHover = async (e) => {
    const rect = timelineContainer.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const percent =
      Math.min(Math.max(0, e.clientX - rect.x), rect.width) / rect.width;

    const iframePlaylistUrls = await getIframePlaylistUrlsFromM3U8();
   
    const iframeIndex = Math.max(
      0,
      Math.floor(percent * iframePlaylistUrls.length)
    );
   
    const thumbnailImageUrl = await extractThumbnailImageUrl(
      iframePlaylistUrls[iframeIndex]
    );
    previewImgRef.current.src = thumbnailImageUrl;
   
  };
```

```
  const extractThumbnailImageUrl = async (iframePlaylistUrl) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(iframePlaylistUrl);
      const iframePlaylistContent = await response.text();

      const thumbnailImageUrl = parseIframePlaylist(iframePlaylistContent);

      return thumbnailImageUrl;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching or parsing iframe playlist", error);
      return "";
    }
  };
```

```
  const parseIframePlaylist = (iframePlaylistContent) => {
    const thumbnailImageUrl = parseIframePlaylistUrl(iframePlaylistContent);
    return thumbnailImageUrl;
  };
```

```
  const parseIframePlaylistUrl = (iframePlaylistContent) => {
    const regex = /#EXT-X-IMAGE:(.+)/;
    const match = iframePlaylistContent.match(regex);
    return match ? match[1] : "";
  };
```

when i hover timeline this function runs

```
  const handleTimeLineUpdate = (e) => {
    const rect = timelineContainer.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const percent =
      Math.min(Math.max(0, e.clientX - rect.x), rect.width) / rect.width;


    updatePreviewImageOnHover(e);

    timelineContainer.current.style.setProperty("--preview-position", percent);

    if (isScrubbing.current) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // thumbnailImgRef.current.src = previewImgSrc;
      timelineContainer.current.style.setProperty(
        "--progress-position",
        percent
      );
    }
  };
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can, or whether this is a good idea. I think all video scrubbers out there don't actually get frames from the video element, but from a spritesheet generated on the server. This is because it would mean _you need to download the entire video_ before you can even display them anyway, in which case you might as well just display the frame as you scrub, but that's slow. I think it's probably even less possible with a streaming format like HLS, which doesn't ever really know about the "entire" video.